# Python and sqlite3 - import text file into database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Thanks for your help. I am new to SQLite3 and was indeed mixing up the two. I have tried the code below but it still does not work.

```
import csv
import sqlite3

# Create the database
connection = sqlite3.connect('addresses.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create the table
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS addresses')
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE addresses
             (ID text, Firstname text, Surname text, Address1 text, Address2 text, Postcode text)''')
connection.commit()

# Load the CSV file into CSV reader
csvfile = open('addresses.txt', 'r')
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

# Iterate through the CSV reader, inserting values into the database
for t in creader:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO  addresses VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', t )

# Close the csv file, commit changes, and close the connection
csvfile.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I get the error
    for t in creader:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: you say you want to load a file called `names.txt` into the database, but you do actually load a file `addresses.txt`… Sorry for raising the obvious, but sometimes… :-)

Comment: Sorry, my typo. Thanks for spotting - I wish it was that simple!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show the error you are getting.

However, it seems that you are confused between sqlite3 and MySQL. These are two completely separate databases, yet your question title refers to "mysqlite3". You connect to a sqlite db file in your code, but then you try to run LOAD DATA which is a MySQL-specific command not supported by sqlite.

You will have to write some Python code to read the CSV file, iterate through, and insert each row to the database. The `csv` module will help.

Comment: As a side note, even better after reading the csv and construct the fields into a list, then do a `executemany` to insert in bulk.

Comment: I've attempted to use the csv module but receive an error. I've edited the initial question. Thanks for your help so far.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is not supported by sqlite.

You should parse the file line by line and generate the inserts
or use the import command

https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

search for .import

Comment: this is a Python question, referring to the CLI documentation is not terribly helpful